# How to call an Angular 4 method from JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to call completePayment() method in my "payment.component.ts" file from  JavaScript function completeCallback() inside "payment.component.html" file. I'm using Angular 4 and I'm trying to call completePayment() method as follows.

```
PaymentComponent.completePayment();
```

But it doesn't work. So how can I call angular 4 method from JavaScript function?

payment.component.ts file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-payment',
      templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css']
    })
    export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

//I want to call this method from JavaScript function
      completePayment(){
        console.log("inside complete payment"); 
      }
    }
```

payment.component.html file

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function completeCallback() {
          console.log('Payment completed');
          PaymentComponent.completePayment();
    }

    </script>
 </head>
<body>
```

Comment: You should look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120893/how-to-call-an-angular-4-method-from-a-standalone-plain-javascript-function) and answers of it.