# Sharing Data between Components (Angular 5, complex app)

Tags: angular

How do I make a service available to all components in a module within my app?

For example, given an app with a structure like:

- app

  - Login.Component
  - UserStory1.module
  - View1.component
  - View2.component
  - ExportableView.Module

    - ExportableView.component
  - UserStory2.module
  - View3.component
  - ExportableView.Module/ExportableView.component
  - CommonModule
  - CommonLanding.component

I want a service UserStory1/LocalService that View 1 and View2 can use to be the source of state for that user story. I don't want that state to be available in UserStory2 -- it should have its own local service.

At first, just to have it available, I had UserStory1/LocalService as a provider in app.module -- and this works. But then when I move it to UserStory1.module it no longer works, each new component that is loaded has its own instance of localservice.

Comment: In this scenario, I think it would be better to adopt the Redux/Flux pattern..

Comment: Directly related: [How to share service between two modules - @NgModule in angular not between to components?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40576714/1260204), [Shared feature module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module), [Services are singletons](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#services-are-singletons), 
[Singleton Services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services), you can register your service as a provider in each module separately, and that would result in a separate instance for each module.

For example

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MyService,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
UserStory1Module
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MyService,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
UserStory2Module
```

Make sure that you do not register a provider inside any of your components.

If you generated the service with Angular CLI, it might be annotated with

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})
MyService
```

You might have to change this to

```
@Injectable()
MyService
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are registering UserStory1/LocalService in multiple modules. As services are of singleton type, so there should be only one instance throughout the application.

If you you are registering UserStory1/LocalService in app.module then this will be available to all components in the app.You don't need to import in another module again.

```
    @NgModule({
  providers: [
    LocalService
  ],
  ...
})
```

In this case the scope of LocalService will be available in the module in which it is registered.

Comment: I dont think that you understand .. I should have explicitly put localservice in there -- it is in /src/app -- it is a peer of userstory1 and userstory2 -- where it s registered in each of those only because userstory2 components are unaware of userstory1