# How to set pass data to another module component using BehaviourSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have used the following approach several times in my projects in order to pass data from one component to another. However, this time I have 2 component: parent (in AppModule) and sidebar (in CoreModule) components and I am trying to pass data from parent to sidebar on a dropdown change. However, it does not work and the `subscribe` method on the sidebar component (in the example child component) is not triggered except from initial loading. Does being on different modules cause this problem? Or any other issue about that?

Here is the [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-share-data-app-mzxjyc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts).

***Update:***

Here is my module relationship:

***parent.module:***

```
imports: [
  SharedModule
],
providers: []
```

***child.module:***

```
imports: [
  SharedModule
],
providers: []
```

***shared.module:***

```
providers: [
    DataService
]
```

When I update as shown above, it still does not work. However, if I move `DataService` in the providers field from `shared.module` to `app.module` it works. But I think it should work when it is only in `shared.module` as shown above. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share service between two modules - @NgModule in angular not between to components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089316/how-to-share-service-between-two-modules-ngmodule-in-angular-not-between-to-c)

Comment: @MichaelD Not exactly, please see my update. The problem is related to modules.

Comment: Since the modules import 'their own version' of the shared module, both have an instance of the service.

Comment: So, what is the proper way for this scene? Should I move the `DataService` from shared.module to app.module's providers section? Is it good habit to use service in AppModule's providers section?

Comment: @GunnarB. Do you mean that it should work with the state in my Update?

Comment: The only way to make a service a singleton (meaning a single instance for the whole application) is by providing it in the root i.e. the app module. Providing it in sub modules is basically the same as providing it directly in a component which will create an instance for the specific component. The whole application is build like a tree, one branch doesn't know about any other since stuff only goes away from the root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to the provider instance in each module, have you tried adding only 1 provider to the top parent module and see the result?

> Using components vs services from other modules There is an important
> distinction between using another module's component and using a
> service from another module. Import modules when you want to use
> directives, pipes, and components. Importing a module with services
> means that you will have a new instance of that service, which
> typically is not what you need (typically one wants to reuse an
> existing service). Use module imports to control service
> instantiation.
>
> The most common way to get a hold of shared services is through
> Angular dependency injection, rather than through the module system
> (importing a module will result in a new service instance, which is
> not a typical usage).
>
> To read about sharing services, see Providers.
> https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Basically, when you import a new module, a new instance of provider is created by each import, so the injection is different, if you need the data to be same for both, you need to handle the provider in the AppModule in this case

Comment: **Exactly!..** But, why? See my update please and let me know why it is not working on shared service?

Comment: I believe the behaviour you need is not supported, here is a quote from the documentation:

Comment: **1.** Thanks a lot. In this scene, could we say that if we need to share service between different modules, we should move this service to only `app.module`?

Comment: **2.** And what about `providedIn: 'platform'` ? Should I still need to use it if I move the shared service to `app.module`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can attach all your services to the root Injector. So instead of providing services to modules or components, set `provideIn: 'root'`:

```
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'}) 
export class DataService { ... }
```

(and don't forget to remove it from `providers` arrays).

My best guest why you experience this issue is because your modules are loaded lazily, what causes them to have their own Injector what finally results in multiple instances of your service.

So either use my suggested way, or read more about `forRoot()` and `forChild()` if you need to keep your service in module's `providers` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. You may also share your ideas about my Update in the question.

Comment: To do that I need more context, preferably a demo with the issue you described